# GLKit: Format Objective-C GLKit parameters for Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, glkit

**Scenario**

I am building an application that manipulates the chroma values of video frames. I am using Objective-C code from another project and translating it into Swift. But I have come across an odd piece of code that I would like to translate to Swift, if I could even figure out what it means. Method is below:

```
- (void)updateUniformValues
{
   // Precalculate the mvpMatrix
   GLKMatrix4 modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(
      self.transform.projectionMatrix, 
      self.transform.modelviewMatrix);
   glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[GMVPMatrix], 1, 0, 
      modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);

   // Texture samplers
   const GLint samplerIDs[1] = {self.texture2d0.name};
   glUniform1iv(uniforms[GSamplers2D], 1, 
      samplerIDs); 
}
```

> note: `self.texture2d0` is of type `GLKEffectPropertyTexture`

The line in question is `const GLint samplerIDs[1] = {self.texture2d0.name};`. I have coded in Objective-C for years before programming in Swift, but I have never seen something like this before. So it's a constant of type `Glint`, but is assigned a value from a `self.texture2d0` block with no return statement? And the `[1]` makes me feel like it should be an `Array`. So confused.

**Question**

What is this line doing? And how can I translate this into Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `samplerIDs` is a `const` array of `GLint`, with a single non-const member, `self.texture2d0.name`.

It would be analogous to:

```
let samplerIDs = [self.texture2d0.name]
```

Comment: Hey Alexander thanks for your input. That would be fine with me, but the compiler complains with "Cannot convert value of type `[GLuint]` to expected argument type `UnsafePointer<GLint>!`". Basically I'm trying to figure out how to create a `UnsafePointer<GLint>!` from the `self.texture2d0.name` value and be able to pass it through to this `glUniform1iv` function.

Comment: @BrandonA Cast the `GLuint` to a `GLint` before adding it to the array. From there, Swift automatically handles the conversion from `Array<T>` to `Unsafe(Mutable)Pointer<T>(?|!)`

Comment: @BrandonA I think the existing ObjC code reinterprets the `GLuint` as a `GLint`, as in, the value of the result is a reinterpretation of the bits of the input. The Swift equivalent would be: `let samplerIDs = [GLint(bitPattern: self.texture2d0.name)]` see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int32/1539852-init

Comment: Thanks @Alexander that sounds promising. I will try this tomorrow and let you know what I find.